# How can i install Wordpress in magento subdirectory

Tags: magento2, nginx, wordpress

On my EC2, Magento is installed on main domain with nginx and now i want to install wordpress on magento subdirectory.
how can i configure nginx for wordpress?
Magento website: domain.com
Wordpress website: domain.com/blog

Regards

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Directory inside Magento's Pub/**Wordpres-Directory** folder.
2. Download wordpress from wordpress.org and Upload Wordpress in that **Wordpres-Directory**
3. Create a database for wordpress and then install worpress by following instruction
   https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/
4. Then open wordpress by [www.yourdomain.com/Wordpres-Directory](http://www.yourdomain.com/Wordpres-Directory)

Comment: It works.
One question, How can we execute PHP files of WordPress that are situated inside /the pub/wp folder?
because we need to add every PHP file inside nginx.conf.sample file before executing it.

Comment: Find the PHP location block (# PHP entry point for the main application) as shown in the below screenshot and add the custom PHP file in nginx.conf.

location ~^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check|test).php$

If we want to allow all the custom PHP files to run then replace the above line as-

location ~* .php$ {

Comment: Thanks,
it works
Can you please help, wordpress shows https://ibb.co/WtJmSMW
when i click on themes.

Comment: Your welcome Ansh. You can provide me bounty if it works for you.
I have not expertise in WP.

Comment: @AnshBhatia if this works for you then mark this answer as useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this extension:-**

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

https://github.com/bentideswell/magento2-wordpress-integration

**Installation Guide**

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/docs/#install

Comment: Hello,
Can we do this without fishpig?

Comment: I used this extension in my past project, not sure without an extension.